# Whitespace in string escape in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I am unable to run my batch command due to character escaping sequence issue.

**Input from python:**

```
import subprocess
print(data) ==> --i "test - testing"
subprocess.call(["c:/foo/boo/file.bat", data])
```

**Batch file:**

```
SET @tt=%1
```

**output:-**

```
C:\foo\boo>SET @tt=" --i \"test
```

**Expected:-**

```
C:\foo\boo>SET @tt=--i "test - testing"
```

Is there a way to escape white space to pass the actual input in batch file? Kindly suggest.

Comment: What does `set @tt=%*` say?

Comment: SET @tt=" --i \"test- testing\"". How will I able to pass multiple inputs if I use *? Also, back slash is required only if there is a space in string else won't work in my case. E.g. SET @tt=--i "test - testing" - Back slash and addition double quotes won't work.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm my suspicion: Phyton passes the complete parameter(s) surrounded by quotes. I don't know phyton, but I'd look for a way to *not*  quote `data`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper quoting and escaping of commands can be tricky. Python has a function in a module to help make this easier: `shlex.split`: ❝Split the string *s* using shell-like syntax.❞

Documentation: [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)

I don't have a way to test your code. Here is an example of what I think you're trying to achieve.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

command = 'c:/foo/boo/file.bat --i "test - testing"'

split_command = shlex.split(command)
print(split_command) # shlex.split handles all the proper escaping
subprocess.call(split_command)
```

OUTPUT from print: `['c:/foo/boo/file.bat', '--i', 'test - testing']`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Single quote does not work in my case.

Comment: Please be more specific about how the single quote is not working. The command can also be written as `command = "c:/foo/boo/file.bat --i 'test - testing'"`

Comment: @dmmfll: they don't work, because *batch* depends on using doublequotes. (except you can turn them around like `command = 'c:/foo/boo/file.bat --i "test - testing"'`)